# Is it possible to split a bought price made with a credit card into some monthly payments?

Tags: banking

I'm from Brazil and here the thing works like that:
If you buy a 300-dollar TV, but the limit of your credit card is 200 dollars, you can split the payment into 2 or even into 12 times. Since, each month you only pay 100 dollars(for 3 portions chosed) to the bank.

It is possible to do this at other countries?

Comment: Which other countries are you asking about?  In the US you can't put more on your credit card than its limit; that's why it's called a limit. Whether the _SELLER_ will be willing to split the charge over multiple months is up to them, but more commonly they'll offer what is known as a "layaway plan" where you don't get to take the item home until you've made enough payments to cover its costs, or they will offer you some form of store credit (after approval) which works like a credit card for that store only, with you making payments to them that include interest on the loan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US some retailers will offer "12 months same a cash" or "no payments for a year" deals. They essentially approve you for a loan via store credit card. Other ways they entice you is with a discount: x% off if you get a credit card today; or free shipping. Some will throw in other benefits in future months.

Often in the fine print of the credit agreement, there will be a clause which states that interest is accrued but not charged until the end of the loan.  If the account is not paid in full by the end of the loan period, or if the card owner defaults at any point on a payment, not only will fees and interest be charged for current amounts, but also going all the way back to the beginning of the loan.

These are generally easy to qualify for, and are done after a quick approval process. The goal is to have you miss the deadline and owe all the forgiven interest; or have you become a long time customer.

Many people use this credit card a a first credit card because it does help build a credit history and a credit score.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, there is something similar called "layaway". You choose the thing you're going to buy, and arrange a payment plan with the retailer. The retailer holds it for you until you've completed all the payments, and the price is guaranteed when you start the plan. There are sometimes fees which can amount to a significant interest rate, but since it's not really a loan, the retailer doesn't do a credit check - after all, they hold both the payments and the item until you've made all the payments.

This used to be pretty common at retailers large or small. It's much less common now, although some large lower-end retailers have started offering it again.